# Why C# is not statically typed but F# and Haskell are?

Tags: c#, haskell, f#

There was a [talk](https://vimeo.com/72870631) given by Brian Hurt about advantages and disadvantages of static typing. Brian said that by static typing he don't mean **C#**, but **F#** and **Haskell**.

Is it because of [`dynamic` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) added to C#-4.0? But this feature is relatively rarely useful. By the way, there are [`⊥`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Bottom) and [`unsafeCoerse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html) in Haskell which obviously are not the same, but something that could blown your head off in runtime similarly like exception thrown as a result of `dynamic`.

Finally, why F# and Haskell could be named a statically typed languages and C# couldn't?

Comment: Well, I guess Mr. Hurt meant "F# and Haskell have *better* static typing than C#" (and not that C# is not statically typed).

Comment: @DocBrown Agreed. The speaker isn't saying "C# Isn't statically typed", he's saying "C#'s static typing system isn't the kind of static typing I'm talking about here" (where F# and Haskell have a much *stronger* and more robust static typing system, by comparison)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm addressing the overlap between Haskell and 
F#'s type systems. The part they share is a simplified subset of a system known sometimes as System F. F# by necessity provides bits and pieces of C#'s type system, but this isn't what the speaker was talking about.

Both C# and Haskell/F# are statically typed, but they're two different flavors.

#### Subtyping

Specifically, C# is a statically typed language with *subtyping*. This means that if you look at the typing rules for C# there's one like

```
 Env |- x : T, T' <: T
 ---------------------
     Env |- x : T'
```

Which means that any well typed term has more than one potential type. This in not the case in (vanilla) Haskell or F#. Every type has a single most general type, a principal type. This has a few benefits like total type inference.

#### Expressions Everywhere

Besides this, Haskell and F# have a greater emphasis on expressions, expressions have types, but statements don't. This means that in C#, the compiler is checking less of your code, because less of your code has types. In Haskell, everything has a real, checkable type.

In substantive terms, every single node on a Haskell AST has a type or kind (or sort). The same cannot be said of a C# one.

#### Sum Types

Beyond this, Haskell and F# have what are known as `sum` types.

```
data Bool = True | False
```

This is how a boolean is defined in Haskell. This provides a few different guarantees than in C#. For example, when there are a discrete number of things in C#, like say, an AST. We can model this with an inheritance hierarchy, but these are open. Anyone can come along and add something to it. We can use an `Enum`, but then there's no sane way to attach data to each tag uniformly. This is what's called a tagged union, and it's up to you to implement/use it correctly, the compiler ain't gonna help.

This makes it very hard to ensure that we've covered all possible nodes of an AST. For example, say you have a function

```
doStuff :: AST -> AST
doStuff (SomeExpr ..) = ...
doStuff (SomeStatement ..) = ...
--// doStuff (SomeIf ...) = Oh noes, we forgot a node
```

The compiler can warn you because it can prove exactly how many nodes there are, ever. In C#, the equivalent would have to be done with downcasting, and then, since the set of nodes in our hierarchy is open, there's no way to issue compile time warnings.

A company, Jane Street, raves about how useful this feature is in their *large* OCaml code base. Watch a few of their [talks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKcOkWzj0_s), they talk quite a bit about how using OCaml impacts them in the Real World.

#### Soapbox

Now I've outlined quite a few differences over System F over many mainstream type systems, but they're all still static type systems. It does bother me when people call Java/C#/C++ "not statically typed" they are. And they certainly give you more compile time guarantees than say, Python. So it's a bit unfair to dismiss them out right.

Comment: But F# has subtyping too. You can write a class and then another class that derives from it.

Comment: And I think the comment about less checking because of statements doesn't make much sense. There is no need to check that the result of an assignment statement is correct.

Comment: @svick I know F# has subtyping, but the point of this talk was adressing HM type systems. Subtyping is kind of a comptability hack. And it mentioned Haskell which doesn't have subtyping

Comment: @svick And in Haskell, every single part of the code is type checked. Including ifs, loops, branches, etc etc. Each of them can be checked and various deductions can be made that aren't possible in a language where some things simply don't have a type.

Comment: Yeah, the but the question asks: how do languages like F# differ from languages like C#? Answering “C# has subtyping” doesn't make much sense, since F# has that too.

Comment: @svick The question is, How do languages like Haskell and F#'s type systems differ from C#. The overlap of Haskell and F# is system F. I could also say Haskell has existentials which can be used to throw away type information, but that wouldn't make sense the part on F#.

Comment: Also, your `bool` example is not very good. `bool` can't be `null` in C#. (But the general point stands.)

Comment: It's actually very easy to encode a closed sum type in C#... here's an example. https://gist.github.com/mausch/6774627 . Also the subtyping part that others have already mentioned.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I feel like your kinda proving my point, 142 lines of code to define a simple sum? And how much of this can the compiler validate for you (in your implementation as well). In Haskell or F# it's 1 line. It's the same argument as encoding subtyping in Haskell, you can do it, but it's so ugly and impractical that it's just not the same benefits as with languages with first class support for it

Comment: What does line count have to do with anything? You say "Anyone can come along and add something to it.", I'm showing how that's not true. I'm not proving your point, I'm proving you wrong. "Ugly", "impractical" aren't objective arguments. I use this encoding every day in my C# day job and find it very useful and "practical". Also, 142 lines includes the entire example. Definitions are 80 LoC including functor and applicative functor operations.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer And how much is checked by the compiler, I mention specifically that sum types are fully checked and validated by the compiler. I wasn't arguing just that they're impractical. But they're impractical and human checked.

Comment: It's interesting that such are encodable, but half my example is that Haskell and F# can warn about missing cases, do proper case handling (with `case` and `match`) which can be optimized to a jump table and checked by the compiler again. without first class sum types these aren't possible.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer your point about sum types appears to be "You can create them in C# too" which is basically the old fallback of in a turing complete language you can create any other language, that doesn't mean the language inherently has the features of that other language. jozefg's point is that sum types are a *language* feature in F# and Haskell

Comment: @JimmyHoffa This is not like that argument at all. For comparison, try to encode type constructor abstraction in C# in an interoperable way. Again, I quote straight from the answer: "We can model this with an inheritance hierarchy, but these are open." -> this is false and it's what I'm criticising, I'm not arguing if it's a language feature or not.

Comment: @jozefg I invite you to analyze my gist again. You'll see that the type is closed and the only catamorphism exposed (the Match method) ensures total case handling, statically. You may not like the syntax (which is a subjective argument), but the core properties are there.

Comment: since when did system F have total type inference? also subtyping doesn't preclude a most general type (well it doesn't have to). the problem that java/c#/c++ have that they can't enumerate subclasses is separate in some ways, since the type system doesn't really have to exist perfectly at the syntax level

Answer (score 2):

There is lot of "marketing religion" and very few science here.

A static_typed laguage must support the definition of types and type checking at compile time, and a dynamic typed language must support the change of the type of the variable at runtime.

The two things are not necessarily mutually exclusive: a language can support both  the paradigms:

the only important thing is that what is defined to be *static* cannot become silently *dynamic*.

Comment: @jozefg: you're right, but in this context the formalism and the actual implementation are irrelevant. Modern languages are often multiparadigm, and can support both the ways in a more or less simple way.  C# just supports both the paradigms. Saying "it's not one", just because "it has also the other" (like the speaker says) is instrumental to other means, but not to proper definition of terms.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly paraphrased and shortened:

> What I don't mean by static typing: C#. What I do mean: F#. Now with an actual solid definition …

That's not a definition, let alone a solid one. I think the answer to why C# isn't statically typed is, but F# is, is: Because the author of the talk said so.

A “definition” like that is completely useless, it doesn't say absolutely anything. And it's impossible to reach any conclusions based on that.

After watching the talk: it basically seems to be a praise of Haskell's type system.

Some of the points don't apply to the languages that supposedly have static typing (you can't easily implement [STM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory) in F#, because it's not pure). Some of the points do apply to the languages that “don't have” static typing (you don't have to worry about nulls much in modern C++; you can write type-safe `Either` in C#).

Comment: @downvoter: it would help if you explained what you think is wrong with my answer.

Comment: I'm an up-voter: your answer has nothing wrong. But since what we are talking about is a religion (or better: two religions at the same time) every believer in one of the two down-votes. Who knows both of them up-votes (but they are few, and considered miscredents from all the others), and all the real "atheist", simply don't care, and use C++11

Comment: I'm a downvoter. The question is asking what did someone mean in a sentence. You are assuming that the person that said that sentence wanted to give a "definition", why do you assume that? Just take a look at the most-voted answer to see that he had a valid point when stating that.

Comment: @knocte “You are assuming that the person that said that sentence wanted to give a "definition"” I quoted him saying that's exactly what he meant. The words “Now with an actual solid definition” are directly from the video.

Comment: @knocte  And jozefg's answer pretty much answers the question “what do *you* think is the difference between C# and F#/Haskell”, not “what did the video author mean”.

Comment: -1  You're grossly misrepresenting what he said.  He made a distinction between the kind of static typing which his talk was about and the technical definition of static typing.  He made the distinction quite clearly, in terms of type systems like Algol-60 vs. type systems like Haskell.  Contrary to your assertion, such a definition is *very* useful (or would you prefer he said "static typing like the type systems of F#, OCaml, and Haskell" instead of "static typing" hundreds of times throughout his talk?).

Comment: And *of course* his talk is basically a praise of Haskell's type system.  The talk was on the pragmatic benefits of static typing systems like Haskell's system to the New York Haskell Users Group.  Whether he's right or wrong about the benefits of that kind of static typing, that's what his talk was about.  Also, you completely missed the point about nulls: in Haskell, there are no null pointer errors.  There is a difference between a kind of error being rare, and that error being *impossible*.

Comment: @MichaelShaw My main problem with the talk is that he claims that where are two groups of languages, one with all these problems and one not. Except that many of his points are actually Haskell-specific. For example in F#, you can't have simple STM, you can have `null` errors etc. So either it's not something inherent in “Haskell-like” type system, or he shouldn't have included all these other languages in there.

Comment: Hi, my answer isn't actually what do I think the differences are, they're objective differences. You can't exactly argue that C# doesn't have principle types and F# does. I'm also a downvoter. Dismissing something that has actual, quantitate differences is being religious. If you prefer that I didn't say System F is better, fine. But pretending that there's no difference is just silly.

Comment: @svick: An actual quote from the talk: "Most of what I say will apply to all of these ... I can actually say stronger things in Haskell than I can any of these others."  Re-watch the video from 4:20 to 5:05.  Compare the words you put in his mouth to what he actually said.

Comment: @jozefg I'm not trying to pretend there is no difference. But I am talking about what's in the video, and he talked about some very specific advantages of Haskell-like languages. And I do think that the mentioned advantages don't have much to do with the distinction between Haskell-like and the rest. Also, if the video you were watching was about System F, then I must have watched something else.

Comment: @jozefg Or let me put it this way: you make far better argument that there are some advantages to Haskell-like languages (and not just Haskell specifically) than the video.

Comment: I agree @jozefg's answer is awesome, but the video is the best talk I've watched in years